# Find the two relations between a and b (Couldn't solve it on my own)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A function **y** is of the form **$y = ax^n+bx$ where a, b , and n** are real numbers. When **$x$** is equal to **1,3,** and **9** respectively, the corresponding values of **$y$** are **4, 6** and **15**.

> Find **two** relations between **a** and **b**, not involving **n**. Find the **exact** numerical values of **a** and **b**, and the value of **n** correct to **3 decimal places.**
>
> Does anybody know how to solve this? My older brother tried explaining it to me, but I didn't understand how he got his answer or even the steps he took to get there.

Answer (score 0):

$4=a+b, 6=a3^n+3b,15=a9^n+9b\Rightarrow \left(\dfrac{6-3b}{a}\right)^2=(3^n)^2=9^n=\dfrac{15-9b}{a}\Rightarrow \dfrac{(6-3b)^2}{a^2}=\dfrac{15-9b}{a}$. thus the $2$ relations are:

$a+b=4, \dfrac{(6-3b)^2}{a^2}=\dfrac{15-9b}{a}$. From these equations you can solve for $a,b$, and then solve for $n$.

Comment: You'll want $4=a+b$.

Comment: $a + b = 4$, you read it too fast it seems

Comment: KfSsOc I still don't understand how to get the answer. Could you please elaborate more on how to obtain the answer. I have a test that I have worked 13 hours on and this was my most troubling problem. Please help me find the solution!

Comment: @user040204  Make the substitution $b = 4 - a$ in the equation $$\frac{(6 - 3b)^2}{a^2} = \frac{15 - 9b}{a}$$ then solve for $a$.